# combine multiple arrays with order of key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example I have like more than 3 different arrays, with element like below:

1st array

```
hello-1
hi-1
```

2nd array

```
ok-two
hi-2
22-two
hello
```

3rd array

```
hi-3rd
hello3
```

And so on...

I want to combine this array in the order one by one. For example the expected output for the 3 arrays above would be:

```
hello-1 
ok-two
hi-3rd
hi-1
hi-2 
hello3 
22-two 
hello
```

I tried `array_merge()`. But it appends the 2nd array after the complete 1st array, which is not what I'm looking for, so here I'm kinda stuck and don't know which functions I can use here. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: The fact that the desired output has "hello-1" before "hello3" makes me unable to see a pattern here. It feels like an IQ-test question. Are you sure that you don't mean to put "hello3" before "hello-1"?

Comment: @KjetilNordin  : I am really sorry for the typo..I have removed it.

Comment: In the mean time, it seems like someone else has answered :). I am not fluent in php, and was just reviewing questions. No reason to be sorry. This is what we are here for, right? to help each other out. I love this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First I get the first element of each array into a sub array, then the second value into the next sub array and so on, that you get this structure of array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello-1
            [1] => ok-two
            [2] => hi-3rd
        )
    //...
)
```

After this you can just loop through each array value with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and get every value into your array.

```
<?php

    $arr1 = [
        "hello-1",
        "hi-1",
    ];

    $arr2 = [
        "ok-two",
        "hi-2",
        "22-two",
        "hello",
    ];

    $arr3 = [
        "hi-3rd",
        "hello3",
    ];

    $arr = call_user_func_array("array_map", [NULL, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3]);
    $result = [];
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v)use(&$result){
        if(!is_null($v))
            $result[] = $v;
    });

    print_r($result);


?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello-1
    [1] => ok-two
    [2] => hi-3rd
    [3] => hi-1
    [4] => hi-2
    [5] => hello3
    [6] => 22-two
    [7] => hello
)
```

Comment: Can I use it more than 3 array ?

Comment: @Vishnu Of course. Just add all your arrays in the order, which you want them in the code here: `$arr = call_user_func_array("array_map", [NULL, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, ...]);`

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to solve this issue

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
        "hello-1",
        "hi-1");

$arr2 = array("ok-two",
              "hi-2",
              "22-two",
              "hello");

$arr3 = array(
    "hi-3rd",
    "hello3");

$max = count($arr1);
$max = count($arr2) > $max ? count($arr2) : $max;
$max = count($arr3) > $max ? count($arr3) : $max;

$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    if (isset($arr1[$i])) {
        $result[] = $arr1[$i];
    }

    if (isset($arr2[$i])) {
        $result[] = $arr2[$i];
    }

    if (isset($arr3[$i])) {
        $result[] = $arr3[$i];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```